# Circuit problem in bathroom

Tags: electrical

It started as a problem with the light in the bathroom. When I switch the light on it causes the GFCI outlet to stop working. However, other lights on the same GFCI outlet still work.

Comment: Offhand I would say you didn't wire the replacement switch properly. Go back and re-check your wiring. If you still need help you should elaborate on your question by providing more detail and actually ask a specific question.

Answer (score 2):

GFCI's trip for a specific reason, that's when there is an imbalance between the current flow of the hot wire of a branch circuit and the neutral of the same circuit. So it's either the fixture itself has some sort of leakage or the switch leg leading to the fixture or the before mentioned you have the switch wired incorrectly. I would try to disconnect the fixture from the circuit and see if the GFCI trips. If it doesn't it's the fixture, replace it. If it does trip it's either the branch wiring or the switch. Be sure and wire nut off the exposed wires while testing without a fixture.

Good luck and stay safe.

Comment: one could try removing the bulb from the fixture and testing, just incase the leakage is in the bulb instead of the entire fixture.